# Terragrunt not findind folder from source repo

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I am using the official Gruntworks samples with the [backend](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-infrastructure-modules-example) (modules) and [frontend](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-infrastructure-live-example) (live) repos.

I wanted (for reasons beyond the scope of this question) to switch to `https` as source.

Therefore I am changing the source of this file

```
terragrunt-infrastructure-live-example/non-prod/us-east-1/qa/mysql/terragrunt.hcl
```

To

```
terraform {
  source = "https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-infrastructure-modules-example//mysql"
}
```

The corresponding `plan` fails:

```
[15/09/21 9:18:41] ➜  mysql git:(adding_atlantis_config) ✗ terragrunt plan
ERRO[0000] Working dir mysql from source https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-infrastructure-modules-example does not exist 
ERRO[0000] Unable to determine underlying exit code, so Terragrunt will exit with error code 1
```

How is this possible since `mysql` dir exists. [Here](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-infrastructure-modules-example/tree/master/mysql) it is.

Answer (score 1):

Should be like

`terraform {
source = "git::https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-infrastructure-modules-example//mysql"
}`